# Bash MacOS X: How to create a tabular menu (or columns)

Tags: bash, macos, menu, inline

I would like to know how can i create an option menu in a tabular form (or columns). So far i got this:

```
echo -e "${starting}" "${cyan}Select your Game Version${ending}"
options=("3.5" "6.5" "10.8" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do 
   case $opt in
        "3.5")
            gameVersion='7.6'
            break
            ;;
        "6.5")
            gameVersion='8.7'
            break
            ;;
        "10.8")
           gameVersion='9.2'
           break
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done

echo -e "${starting}" "Your game Version is ${green}"${gameVersion}"${ending}!"
```

This works nicely. This is what i get when i am running it:

```
project  Select your Game Version
1) 3.5
2) 6.5
3) 10.8
4) Quit
```

But i would like to have it this way:

```
project  Select your Game Version
project  1) 3.5 
project  2) 6.5
project  3) 10.8
project  4) Quit
project  #? (users input)
```

Is there any way to build this menu like this?

Comment: Are you using a script to run this?

Comment: Look at this useful answer - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203309/can-i-change-how-select-options-are-displayed